# Apache Server Running Django Project showing only "Index of /" and the names of project files instead of running the site

Tags: apache-http-server, python, django, mod-wsgi

When I navigate to the site, it only shows 'Index Of /' and then the files I have inserted in my htdocs. I've looked at a lot of people with this same error but haven't found a solution yet. I'm using Django, Apache, and a mod-wsgi file.

Here's the code for my httpd-vhosts.conf file. Obviously, there's still some of the dummy data in there, but that shouldn't matter right? This is my first time getting a server up and it is blowing my mind.

I think the error is somewhere in this file, because everything works up until this point.

Any help is much appreciated! (Let me know if it would be easier to see how other files are set up)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

WSGIPythonPath C:/Apache24/htdocs/chf
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName chfestival.example
ServerAdmin johnny@chfestival.example
DocumentRoot C:/Apache24

Alias /static/ C:/Apache24/htdocs/chf/static/

<Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/chf/static>
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Apache24/htdocs/chf/CHF/wsgi.py WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/chf>
<Files wsgi.py> Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```